Eye rig not rotating properly
I cant seem to get my eyes to just rotate according to the rig, rather than deforming like this.




Did you make this skeleton? Are there any other hidden bones?

hello please share your file (at least the armature + eyes)

The eye bones almost look like they've been moved in the Y(?) direction after your rig was parented.  Perhaps (in Armature EDIT mode) try to unlock the Position params for the eye bones, adjust their location, and if satisfied, apply location and re-lock Position.

@moonboots its gonna take a bit of time. but its uploading

@moonboots uploaded

@james_t im gonna try and ill give an update

It looks like your bones are positioned away from your eyes instead of being in the eyes' center of mass. Bones act like parents. When you rotate a bone, the vertices assigned to that bone rotate around the bone relative to the weights strengths.

So if you want your eyes to rotate around themselves, you need to have their bone at the center of the eyes' mesh.

To do this, you can select the eye mesh in edit mode, press ⇧ ShiftS > Cursor to selected. Then in the armature in Pose mode, select the bone of that eye and press ⇧ ShiftS > Selection to Cursor to move it to where the center of the eye mesh should be. Then with that same bone selected, press ⎈ Ctrl⇧ ShiftC then ⎈ Ctrl⇧ ShiftV to copy the pose and paste it to its opposite bone. If it doesn't work, check that your eye bones have the same names with the .L and .R suffixes as in my GIF.
Finally, the eyes mesh should have moved to a different place with your bones, you can fix this by selecting all bones in Pose Mode and pressing ⎈ CtrlA > Apply to Rest Pose.

thank you so much. I will try this as soon as I can and Ill update you :>

To add to Lauloque's answer, if you select the vertices of the eyes you'll see that they are assigned to several vertex groups while they should be only part of eye.L or eye.R:

To fix that, remove the eye vertices from these bad vertex groups:


thank you so much. I'll update you as soon as I can
